# restlet maven dependency issue

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am getting this error on doing mvn clean install of my project.

I have added the dependency in pom.xml as well and also present in my m2 repository.

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.Test:ESB-Https:bundle:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.camel:camel-restlet:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630347 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.6: Could not transfer artifact org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.3.6 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [redhat-ga-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/, default, releases), apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of maven block *http* requests. Try updating your repositories URL to use *https* instead.